# How to install MySql packages for Asp.Net 5.0 on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, kpm

I'm trying to connect to MySql from Asp.Net 5.0 MVC project on Ubuntu 14.04. I managed to get a connection following [this](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/mysql/) example on the mono site. Now I have an MVC project created using the [asp.net yo generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet). I have included System.Data and MySql.Data.MySqlClient at the top of my model class but I keep getting an error that I'm missing an assembly reference to System.Data but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install System.Data and MySql.Data using the following commands:

```
kpm install System.Data.Common 1.0.0-beta2

kpm install MySql.Data
```

You should now see both packages listed as dependencies in your package.json

You can browse all the kpm packages on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/)